# Error when using comparison operators in conjunction with macros

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, compiler-warnings

- I have two 2-D arrays close and open
- I have defined 2 macros min(a,b) and max(a,b) as

  ```
  #define min(a,b) (a<b?a:b)
  #define max(a,b) (a>b?a:b)
  ```

And I'm using an expression in my code which is as follows:

```
max( close[i-1][ii], open[i-1][ii] ) < max( close[i-2][ii], open[i-2][ii] )
```

However, this returns the following warning:

> warning: comparisons like X<=Y<=Z do not have their mathematical meaning

I believe the preprocessor is doing something of the sort of 
`a<b<c`
replacement which might explain the warning from the compiler. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure you copied your code right, including parentheses? This works for me, but a minor error in parentheses would cause the warning you're seeing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros just replace text so you need to parenthesize everything.

```
#define min(a,b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))
#define max(a,b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))
```

If you are using C++, there are much better alternatives though.  Inline functions have the same performance as macros while being much better behaved.

Comment: Using parenthesized code or std::min / std::max doesn't solve it. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

use std::max and std::min instead

Your macros have side effects the way you are using them.

Comment: He's passing them fixed variables, it should be fine

Comment: What kind of side effects are you referring to?

Comment: Using parenthesized code or std::min / std::max doesn't solve it. Any other ideas?

Comment: This is getting stranger. I tried a dummy code with just the macros and it works. However, when I use it in my main code, it issues warnings:

if ( max( close[i-1][ii], open[i-1][ii] ) < max( close[i-2][ii], open[i-2][ii] ) &&              
     min( close[i-1][ii], open[i-1][ii] ) > min( close[i-2][ii], open[i-2][ii] ) 
   ) ct++;

Comment: Parenthesizing the macro usage in the main code worked!:
if ((max(close[i-1][ii], open[i-1][ii]))>(min(close[i-2][ii], open[i-2][ii]))) does it! :)

Thank you!